# C++ syntax when initializing the instance variables

Tags: c++

What does it mean in C++

> ```
> int x;
> x = GetMethod("OpponentCalledOnTurn") == 1;
> ```

Note : why is there a "==1" part.

I am Novice to c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set `x` to `1` if `GetMethod("OpponentCalledOnTurn") == 1` evaluates to `true` and to `0` if it evaluates to `false`.

The underlying rule here: A boolean value can be converted to other integer types, that will result in `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is the equality comparison operator.

So `GetMethod("OpponentCalledOnTurn") == 1` first calls the function `GetMethod`, passing the given string literal as an argument. The return value of that function call is then compared to `1`. That comparison evaluates to either `true` if the return value *equals* `1`, or `false` otherwise.

`x =` then assigns that `true` or `false` to `x`. Since `x` is of type `int` and not `bool` (the type of `true` and `false`), `true` is converted to `1` and `false` is converted to `0`.

Effectively, if `GetMethod("OpponentCalledOnTurn")` returns `1`, `x` will end up equaling `1`, otherwise it will end up equaling `0`.